# How to keep the values of first activity and see them on switching back from second activity to first activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, onsaveinstancestate

I entered some text in the text boxes on first activity.

Then, On pressing the "SAVE" button, I am moved to the second activity.

Now, On pressing the "BACK" button, I am dropped back on the first activity where i am unable to see the values/text i entered before.

I have tried using shared preferences also.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OTl8iTGYE2iyQN74pZBPDNT31d093Y2P) is my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.madhur.intentclear;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText tv1 = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final EditText tv2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText tv3 = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        final Button bt1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1=getSharedPreferences("value1",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences1.edit();
                editor.putString("tv1",tv1.getText().toString());

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2=getSharedPreferences("value2",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor2=sharedPreferences2.edit();
                editor2.putString("tv2",tv2.getText().toString());

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences3=getSharedPreferences("value3",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor3=sharedPreferences3.edit();
                editor3.putString("tv3",tv3.getText().toString());

                editor.apply();
                editor2.apply();
                editor3.apply();
               tv1.setText(String.valueOf(sharedPreferences1.getString("tv1",null)));
               tv2.setText(String.valueOf(sharedPreferences2.getString("tv2",null)));
               tv3.setText(String.valueOf(sharedPreferences3.getString("tv3",null)));

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("tv1",tv1.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("tv2",tv2.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("tv3",tv3.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Main2Activity.java**

```
package com.example.madhur.intentclear;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        final TextView tv1=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        final TextView tv2=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        final TextView tv3=findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        Button button=findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button button1=findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2=findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle intent=getIntent().getExtras();
                tv1.setText(intent.getString("tv1"));
                tv2.setText(intent.getString("tv2"));
                tv3.setText(intent.getString("tv3"));
            }
        });

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String clear="";

                tv1.setText(clear);
                tv2.setText(clear);
                tv3.setText(clear);
               m1();

            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
Intent intent1=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
    }
    public void m1()
    {String clear="";
        try {

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream2;
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream3;
            fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("et1.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileOutputStream.write(clear.getBytes());

            fileOutputStream2 = openFileOutput("et2.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileOutputStream2.write(clear.getBytes());

            fileOutputStream3 = openFileOutput("et3.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileOutputStream3.write(clear.getBytes());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.madhur.intentclear.MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.13" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.87" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.06" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.18" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.29" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.43" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.58" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.73" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.82" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.24" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.77" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
       android:hint="Enter name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:hint="Enter phone number"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:hint="Enter Email Adress"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
android:text="SAVE"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline12"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline9" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_Main2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.madhur.intentclear.Main2Activity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline16"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline13"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline14"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline15" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline19"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline13"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline14"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline20" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline17"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline13"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline14"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline18" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="249dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33854166" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.031311154" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.13" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.38" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.29" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.26" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.16" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="SHOW TEXT"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline13"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline14"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline17" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="CLEAR TEXT"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline13"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline14"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="BACK"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline13"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline14"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please edit the question and post the code here and not host it somewhere else.

Comment: @Rinav, I am unable to edit the code, Honestly, I am really sick of it. I am looking for a paid service so that i don't have to scratch my head for formatting the code. If "x" amount of time i spend to format the code then finding the solution on internet will take even less amount of time. Do you know any paid service ?

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting and learn how to format code while posting questions on SO. It really helps to answer questions and understand quickly

Comment: I did not down vote you :(

Comment: @ModusTollens, Can you show me by posting the same question i am trying to post ?. I really need it.

Comment: @Rinav, I strongly apologize, Thanks for helping me out.Modulus Tollens, Can you assist me now ?

Comment: @MadhurAhlawat Thanks for the apology, I deeply appreciate that. I removed my close vote after you edited your code into the question, and I see that you don't need my help editing your question any more. I am going to remove my comments. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Use **savedInstanceState** Bundle in onCreate

The **savedInstanceState** is a reference to a Bundle object that is passed into the onCreate method of every `Android Activity`. Activities have the ability, under special circumstances, to restore themselves to a previous state using the data stored in this bundle. If there is no available instance data, the savedInstanceState will be null.

> For example, the savedInstanceState will always be null the first time
>   an Activity is started, but may be non-null if an Activity is
>   destroyed during rotation.

**When do I save things to the Bundle?**

All activities have an onSaveInstanceState method that can be overridden. When this method is called, any state-related data should be placed into the outState Bundle. This method is called when an Activity is being backgrounded (either after onPause() or onStop(), depending on different factors).

**What should be saved?**

The savedInstanceState Bundle should only save information directly related to the current Activity state. Examples of this include:

A typical example is **User-submitted data** – If a user writes their username into a text box, they would expect the username to still be present when the Activity is resumed. **This data should be saved in onSaveInstanceState then restored when the Activity is re-created**.

In your onCreate function, this Bundle is handed back to the program. The best way to check if the application is being reloaded, or started for the first time is:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
// Then the application is being reloaded
}
```

To get the data back out, use the get* functions just like the put* functions. The data is stored as a name-value pair. This is like a hashmap. You provide a key and the value, then when you want the value back, you give the key and the function gets the value. Here's a short example.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   outState.putString("message", "This is my message to be reloaded");
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String message = savedInstanceState.getString("message");
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

// Promoting Local variable to Field

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tv1;
    private TextView tv2;
    private TextView tv3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: useless, i cant access tv1 inside the onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) method.

Comment: Anyways, Thanks for voting down and trying to help me Rinav.

Comment: You need to promote `tv1` to a field rather than local variable.

Comment: It suggests me to make tv1 not static. When i declare it final, it denies to assign anything to it & when i leave it outside the "onCreate" method and make it "non-final", it gives me a "NullPointerException".

Answer (score 0):

Use shared Preference to store values temporally/ permanent

**EDITED**
Sorry i was not seen the code after seen code.

Your setting values inside `onlCick` again. You have set the values outside the `onClick`

**Solution**

Create one global `SharedPreferences` with `MODE_PRIVATE`, set the values `onClick` and read values on `onCreate`(outside `onClick`).

Comment: Thanks, it worked, Now i am trying to delete the content saved in the shared preferences of first activity, I mean, when i press the "CLEAR" button which is present on the second activity, the contents of first activity's shared preferences should be removed. How to do that.

Comment: Global instance you have right use that `sharedPrefs.edit().clear().apply()`

Comment: Hi! Hemant, I am trying to add onClickActionListener on multiple buttons at the same time, could you please assist me in doing that ?, I'm not getting onClick in xml layout file correctly, if its the way, please assist me.

Comment: Multiple layout has same `ClickListener` and different ID's. if your widget is not able click means set `clickable` and `focusable` to true on the layout. In Activity inside `ClickListener` menthod use ID's to differentiate to click